# Left-clicking a text input in IE8 and Firefox

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-8, textinput

This seems like a silly question since it doesn't have anything to do with programming, so I expect a few silly answers.  But this is making me crazy.

I develop in FF but I'm forced to test in IE8 since that's the only officially-supported browser here (way better than when I had to support IE6!!!).

In testing, I have to fill out the same forms over and over.  In FF this is much faster since I just left-click in a text input box and get a list of old values.  In IE8, it always seems like I have to start from scratch.  The only input that seems to keep old values is a username.

Is there some feature in IE8 that I don't have turned on?  I'd like to use it before carpal-tunnel sets in!

Comment: Not in front of a Windows machine, so haven't tried it, but I thought you could enable form filling from previous form entries via these instructions in IE 8: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100621134647AANnKdx - not sure if it saves previously filled in entries - I suppose that's the limitation you're concerned about?

Comment: That's what I thought it was, but it doesn't seem to help.  I'm not sure why it says "(outside of Internet Explorer)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there isn't. That's why newer browsers are better.

Why not pre-populate your forms for testing purposes.

Comment: UGH. I was afraid of that!

I occasionally do that, but it's not possible once I move my code to the test system, where file-editing isn't permitted (got in trouble for that a couple of weeks ago).

Comment: Take a look at Selenium - it's a proper automated testing suite.

Comment: Selenium sounds interesting, since I doubt I can talk my company into buying anything.